# BottomSheetDialog remains hidden after dismiss by dragging down

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottom-sheet

I am pretty curious about the behavior of the `BottomSheetDialog` when  it is dismissed : when the user draggs it down to hide it, it will remain hidden, even if `bottomSheetDialog#show()` is called after. This only happens when it is dragged down, not when the user touches outside or when `bottomSheetDialog#dismiss()` is called programatically.

It is really annoying because I have a pretty big `bottomSheetDialog` with a recyclerview inside, and I have to create a new one every time I want to show the `bottomSheetDialog`.

So instead of just doing this :

```
if(bottomSheetDialog != null){
   bottomSheetDialog.show();
else{
   createNewBottomSheetDialog();
}
```

I have to create one every time.

Am I missing something or is it the normal behavior ? (Btw I use `appcompat-v7:23.2.1`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I finally managed to solve this problem by looking directly into the `BottomSheetDialog` implementation, and I discovered it was nothing but a simple `Dialog` wrapped into a regular `BottomSheet`.
The problem was in the `BottomSheetCallBack` :

```
@Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet,
            @BottomSheetBehavior.State int newState) {
        if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            dismiss();
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs when the state HIDDEN is reached which happens when the dialog is dismissed by being dragged down. After that the dialog stays hidden even if `bottomSheetDialog.show()` is called. The most simple fix I found was to remove this state and replace it by the COLLAPSED state.

I create a `classCustomBottomSheetDialog`, copied the entire `BottomSheetDialog` class and added a single line to fix the problem :

```
@Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet,
                               @BottomSheetBehavior.State int newState) {

        if (newState == CustomBottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {

            dismiss();
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(CustomBottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
    }
```

Here is the final code:

```
public class CustomBottomSheetDialog extends AppCompatDialog {

    public CustomBottomSheetDialog (@NonNull Context context) {
        this(context, 0);
    }

    public CustomBottomSheetDialog (@NonNull Context context, @StyleRes int theme) {
        super(context, getThemeResId(context, theme));
        // We hide the title bar for any style configuration. Otherwise, there will be a gap
        // above the bottom sheet when it is expanded.
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    protected CustomBottomSheetDialog (@NonNull Context context, boolean cancelable,
            OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResId) {
        super.setContentView(wrapInBottomSheet(layoutResId, null, null));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setLayout(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        super.setContentView(wrapInBottomSheet(0, view, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.setContentView(wrapInBottomSheet(0, view, params));
    }

    private View wrapInBottomSheet(int layoutResId, View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        final CoordinatorLayout coordinator = (CoordinatorLayout) View.inflate(getContext(),
                R.layout.design_bottom_sheet_dialog, null);
        if (layoutResId != 0 && view == null) {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResId, coordinator, false);
        }
        FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) coordinator.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setBottomSheetCallback(mBottomSheetCallback);
        if (params == null) {
            bottomSheet.addView(view);
        } else {
            bottomSheet.addView(view, params);
        }
        // We treat the CoordinatorLayout as outside the dialog though it is technically inside
        if (shouldWindowCloseOnTouchOutside()) {
            coordinator.findViewById(R.id.touch_outside).setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if (isShowing()) {
                                cancel();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
        return coordinator;
    }

    private boolean shouldWindowCloseOnTouchOutside() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11) {
            return true;
        }
        TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (getContext().getTheme()
                .resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.windowCloseOnTouchOutside, value, true)) {
            return value.data != 0;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static int getThemeResId(Context context, int themeId) {
        if (themeId == 0) {
            // If the provided theme is 0, then retrieve the dialogTheme from our theme
            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(
                    R.attr.bottomSheetDialogTheme, outValue, true)) {
                themeId = outValue.resourceId;
            } else {
                // bottomSheetDialogTheme is not provided; we default to our light theme
                themeId = R.style.Theme_Design_Light_BottomSheetDialog;
            }
        }
        return themeId;
    }

    private BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback mBottomSheetCallback
            = new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet,
                @BottomSheetBehavior.State int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                dismiss();
                bottomSheetBehavior.setState(CustomBottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: I couldn't copy and paste this code because there's no reference to  bottomSheetBehavior when you're setting the state.

Answer (score 8):

**Update:** The problem has been resolved at some version of the support library. I don't really know the exact version that fixes it but in 27.0.2 it is fixed.

**Note:** The URL does no longer refer to the issue described due to some modification on the URL schema by Google.

A workaround better than copying the whole class just to add a single line

```
// Fix BottomSheetDialog not showing after getting hidden when the user drags it down
    myBottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialogInterface;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) bottomSheetDialog
                    .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
        }
    });
```

see: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202396#c7

Comment: Setting the state to expanded in onShow doesn't solve anything, you have to get into into the bottomSheetcallback to remove the state hidden whenever it's set.

Comment: @DavidSeroussi I've test it myself and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have sample demo I hope that is useful.

```
public class BottomListMenu extends BottomSheetDialog {
    private List<MenuDTO> menuList;
    private OnMenuItemTapped menuTapListener;

    public BottomListMenu(@NonNull Context context, List<MenuDTO> menuList, OnMenuItemTapped menuTapListener) {
        super(context);
        this.menuList = menuList;
        this.menuTapListener = menuTapListener;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_menu_list);
        RecyclerView rcvList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcv_menu_list);
        rcvList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        BottomSheetMenuListAdapter adapter = new BottomSheetMenuListAdapter(getContext(), this, menuList, menuTapListener);
        rcvList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

--- Use ---

```
BottomListMenu menu = new BottomListMenu(MainActivity.this, MenuUtils.getListMenu(MainActivity.this), new OnMenuItemTapped() {
    @Override
    public void onClickMenuItem(MenuDTO menu) {
        if (menu.getMenuTitle().equals(getString(R.string.menu_edit))) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Edit Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (menu.getMenuTitle().equals(getString(R.string.menu_delete))) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Delete Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (menu.getMenuTitle().equals(getString(R.string.menu_attach))) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Attach Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
menu.show();
```

-- Full Sample Code Available Here --

https://github.com/bita147/BottomSheetDialog

Comment: Thank you but how does this answer my question ?